# How do I keep a fixed background image above the footer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a background image in the body CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url("bg-image.jpg");
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: black;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This is fine except the footer then overlaps the image when scrolled down. I want the background image to scroll up with the footer and only at the footer (so the footer doesn't cut off the bottom of the image). Is it possible to only do this in CSS or would JS be needed? Either way how do I go about doing this?

The footer css is:

```
#footer {
    border-top: 1px #black solid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(16,16,16,0.9);
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by having two separate containers, one for content and one for footer, inside of body. That way content will push the footer down, and they'll stay separated.

```
.content{
    background: url('imageUrl') center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; // cover, contain or 100%, whichever you prefer
    background-position: fixed;
    min-height: 1000px; // demonstration purpose
}

.footer{
    height: 50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vpwn8ers/